# Fact table changes

Tags: sql, database, etl, data-warehouse, business-intelligence

**CONTEXT**

I'm trying to create a sales fact table.
Each row represent a product from an order for a customer.
Among other fields, I have these 3 specific fields:

- **purchasing_price**
- **selling_price**
- **margin**

**PROBLEM**

In  our company, when we sell a product, I don't know exactly the purchasing price, because I will pay this product later and the purchasing price will be based on the exchange rate at the payment date.
I usually know the real purchasing price between 1 week and 2 month after the order date.
Indeed, my firm got an arrangement that allow us to pay our suppliers each 15th of the next month, from the month when we receive the product from our supplier.
Since we have suppliers in different countries the exchange rate raise some issues.

**RESULTS AWAITING**

I had to generate 2 monthly reports and 1 annual report :
- 1 report on the 1st of each month based on the exchange rate of the order date
- 1 report on the 15th of each month based on the exchange rate of the payment date (which is the exchange rate of the current date because we pay our suppliers each 15th of the month)
- 1 annual report based on the exchange rate of the payment date (which could sometimes be 2 month after the order date)

**EXAMPLE**

1. I order a product on 3rd July.
2. This product is only delivered on the 7th August
3. Then I will pay the product the 15th September based on the exchange rate of this date.

**SOLUTIONS**

So far, I find only 3 solutions:

1. a) create 1 row in the fact table and 2 fields: **real_purchasing_price** (which would be equal to 0) and **temporary_purchasing_price** (which would automatically be equal to the purchasing price based on the exchange rate of the order date).
   b) once I paid the product, I know the right exchange rate, therefore I can update this row an fulfill the field **real_purchasing_price** with the purchasing price based on the exchange rate of the payment.
2. a) create 1 row in the fact table with the **purchasing_price** based on the exchange rate of the order date.
   b) once I paid the product, I know the right exchange rate therefore I can create 1 new row in the fact table almost similar to the first one, but this time with the **purchasing_price** based on the exchange rate of the payment date.
3. a) create a row in the fact table with the **purchasing_price** based on the exchange rate of the order date
   b) once I paid the product I know the right exchange rate therefore I can update this row and replace the **purchasing_price** by the one based on the right exchange rate.

The 4th solution belongs to you.

Thx for your help.
Don't hesitate to ask me about more details.

Have a good day,

Comment: I think you should add a true/false column (OR value 0, 1) to check completed your order

Comment: Ok thx, so I should add this column only if I choose the solution 2) right?

Comment: Yes. Let's try it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your **order** goes through three stages:

- **ordered**
- **delivered**
- **purchasing price is known**

One data-warehouse design approach is the **immutability** (insert only,make no updates).

This approach would lead to creation of three fact records for your order

**Ordered Event**

with attributes

```
 orderId, productId, orderDate  and sellingPrice
```

**Delivered Event**

```
 orderId, DeliveryDate,
```

Note that the order and delivery records are uniquely  correlated with the OrderId (under simplified assumption of only one product per order).

Both of those events are stored in separate fact table or in a common one - it depends on the full attribute definition in you case.

The  **purchasing price** is stored in a separate table with attributes

```
productId, entryDate, validFromDate, ValidToDate, purchasingPrice
```

The table is filled based on your rules on the 15th of following month (entryDate) with the validity interval for the preceding month.

The crucial role of this table is to support the query with productId and validDate and return either the purchasing price or *unknown*.

Based on this design you may setup an **access view** (simple view, materialize view or other solution) providing the current state of the order

```
 orderId, productId, orderDate, sellingPrice,
 DeliveryDate, -- NULL if not delivered
 purchasingDate,
 purchasingStaus -- 1 purchased, 0 - not yet purchased
 purchasingPrice
```

The `purchasingDate` is calculated based on the delivery date based on the business rule. The `purchasingStatus` is a result of comparison of the reporting date and purchasing Date.

The `purchasingPrice` is either the estimation *last known price of the product* or the proper purchasing price.

You may also ask why is **immutability** in data-warehouse design important.
It is similar to transaction concept in OLTP. In troubles you may *rollback* the data to some point in the past using **auditing dimension** and reload it again. If you update this is much more complex.

**Small Example**

On 15.2. you get purchasing price for product A in January

**Purchasing Price Table**

```
 entryDate = 15.2.
 validFrom = 1.1.
 validTo = 31.1.
 purchacingPrice = 100
```

Order of product A on 1.3. creates a record in **Order Event Table**

```
 orderDate = 1.3.
 sellingPrice = 200
 ...
```

You may report this event with "last know purchacing price", which is currently 100. 
(Lookup in Purchasing Price Table with **orderDate** gives no valid result, last stored value is returned)

Delivery on 10.3. creates a record in **Delivery Event Table**

```
 deliveryDate = 10.3.
 ....
```

The exact purchasing price is still unknown (Lookup in Purchasing Price Table with **deliveryDate** gives no valid result, last stored value is returned)

On 15.4. new purchasing price is entered in  **Purchasing Price Table** for March.
From this points the real  **purchacing price** is known.

Comment: Thank you @Marmite Bomber for this complete answer.
I got one last question:
About the price I don't understand, let's say I had a row with the estimation _italic_last know price of the product_italic_

Comment: The answer above has been cut sorry

Thank you @Marmite Bomber for this complete answer.
Just to be sure I understand very well your solution. Do you agree on what follows
1) Let's say I add a row with the estimation _italic_last know price of the product_italic_ I will then fulfill the field purchasingStatus with value 0.
2) Once I know the real purchasing price, I will add a new row with the real purchasing price and I will fufill the field purchasingStatus with 1

Is-it right? In that way there is indeed no UPDATE :)

Comment: @seeusoon correct, I added an example to make it more clear.

Comment: In fact with your solution, I don't need a Currency_Table anymore, right?

I think I'm gonna use only one unique Table_Fact :
order_id, product_id, order_date, selling_price, purchasing_price, purchasing_status

I will add one row in this Fact_Table right after the order is created so I'm gonna use the "last known price" and purchasing_status = 0

And once I know the real purchasing price, I add another row in this Fact_Table with the real purchasing price and purchasing_status = 1

Does it seem like an efficient solution to you?

Thx anyways.

Answer (score 1):

I actually choose to use a currency table and to add a field payment_date which allow me to match each row of the fact table with right exchange rate in the currency table.

Nevertheless, I have to UPDATE each row of the fact table to add the payment_date once I know it.

I couldn't find a better solution so far.

Thx everyone.

Comment: I thing this is a good direction. See the note on updates in my (sorry that late) answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that for purchasing price, you have a componet which is fixed and another which is variable and depends on exchange rate. (say p*x where x is exchange rate)

I would suggest to create a new fact table, say `exchange_rates` with different countries exchange rates and timestamp. Now the column `purchasing_price` in your fact table, should be a result of join from `exchange_rates` table for that country.

Lets say `current_values` column hold exchange rate.

```
    EXCHANGE_RATES
    +-------------+---------------+---------------+-----------+
    | EXCHANGE_ID | EXCHANGE_NAME | CURRENT_VALUE | TIMESTAMP |
    +-------------+---------------+---------------+-----------+
    |           1 | JAPAN         |           100 |  20151021 |
    +-------------+---------------+---------------+-----------+
```

While populating purchasing price, use this value from `EXCHANGE_RATES` to get correct values.

```
    ORDER_DETAIL_FACT       
    +----------+---------+------------------+---------------+--------+
    | ORDER_ID | PRODUCT | PURCHASING_PRICE | SELLING_PRICE | MARGIN |
    +----------+---------+------------------+---------------+--------+
    |      101 |      11 | 50*100           |          6000 |   1000 |
    +----------+---------+------------------+---------------+--------+
```

Let me know if you need help with its implementation.

Comment: Thx, sure I got your point. But, your solution works only if I have the right exchange rate at the same time I add the row in the fact table.

My problem is that I will get the right exchange rate at the time I will pay for this product which could be in a month.

Tell me if it's not clear enough

Comment: So I don't know whether I should add a new row with the right exchange rate or whether I should update my previous row with the right exchange rate or if there is a proper solution. I think all e-commerce company face the same issue in their Data Warehouse.

Comment: Your table will have `purchasing price` based on the latest value of exchange `current_value`. As soon as it is updated, you can trigger a change to your `ORDER_DETAIL_FACT` to reflect the correct `PURCHASING_PRICE` value

Comment: So you recommended to me a solution close to my number 3) solution. which is once you know the real exchange rate used for the payment you erase the initial value of the `purchasing_price` and replace this one with the new exchange rate?